# How do I retrieve items that are related to the username/userid in swift/parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I tried many variations. Separately, it works fine and prints the correct values, but I want to query the items that match the userid. I tried many things and all it returns are blank `[]`. Can somebody help me with this?

The items that show up on the tableview should be the ones that match with its userid/username

```
var itemList = [String]()
var userid = [String]()
var names = [String]()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let query = PFQuery(className:"reservedCust")
    query.whereKey("item", containedIn: names)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (objects, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {


            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {


                    if let item = object["item"] as? String {

                        self.itemList.append((object["item"] as? String)!)

                    }

                    if let name = object["userid"] as? String {

                        self.names.append((object["userid"] as? String)!)

                    }
               }       
            }
            print(self.userid)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }else {

        }
    }
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return itemList.count
} 

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = itemList[indexPath.row]     

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where do you put anything in `names` - names seems to be an empty array and then you use `containedIn:names` in your query, so you will get no objects back. You say you want to match the user ID - what user ID? The current user?  There is no user id in your query

Comment: where do you have the userId? is it the array `userid = [String]()`? so do you want objects with userIds that match the userId string?

Comment: what is item in your PFObject? is it a pointer or just a string?

Comment: the userid is listen in parse. isn't this code `if let name = object["userid"] as? String {

                        self.names.append((object["userid"] as? String)!)

                    }` filling up the names list

Comment: yes i want the objects with user id to match the userid string